# Where should I keep data to be used by my android app?

Tags: android, store

Sorry for my poor English. I want to store data for each level in a .txt file. I found tutorial about how to create it but I need a prestored file. Could you give me a hand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ! I have to use openRawResource() and keep the file in the res/raw folder. Maybe it helps to another person who searches the same.